# How to check WP Customize Control

Tags: theme-customizer

I trying this directly in my theme:

`$mods = $wp_customize->get_control('header_text');
 if (isset($mods)) {
    echo 'YES';
} else {
    echo 'No';
}`

But nothing happened. and in debug.log : undefined variable wp_customize...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but if you're wanting to manipulate customizer controls until the `customize_register` action has fired. So do something like this:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function( $wp_customize ) {
    $control = $wp_customize->get_control( 'header_text' );
    if ( $control ) {
        error_log( 'header_text control exists' );
    } else {
        error_log( 'header_text control does not exist' );
    }
}, 100 );
```

Comment: I just wanted to check and run a conditional to change something on the theme based on that.

I'm not good with programming. Thank you! Your way is better!

Comment: But mine also worked

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_theme_mod](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod) and this work:

`$mod = get_theme_mod('header_text');
 if ( $mod != 0 ) {
    # code...
    echo 'YES';
} else {
    echo 'No';
}`

In this case I wanted to check if the Title and the slogam of the site was hidden or not.

To get the string> ID of the MOD is simply. inspect the option with the Customizer open, as show the image:

[image]